# Constexpr, templates and array size

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to pass template argument to function call and the return value use as size of an array ie

```
constexpr int myPow(int a, int b){
  int result = 1;
  for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    result *= a;
  return result;
}

template <int N>
class testClass{
public:
  testClass(){}
  int array[myPow(2,N)];
};

int main(){
  testClass<3> A;
  return 0;
}
```

compiler errors:

```
~ $ g++-4.6 test.cpp -std=gnu++0x
test.cpp: In function ‘constexpr int myPow(int, int)’:
test.cpp:6:1: error: body of constexpr function ‘constexpr int myPow(int, int)’ not a return-statement
test.cpp: At global scope:
test.cpp:12:23: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Your function cannot be more than one `return ...;` (until C++14) that only uses compile-time tools or it won't give back a compile-time constant.

Comment: Well post the relevant code (i.e. the one in `myPow` and a minimal complete `testClass`, and the actual compiler error.

Comment: Did you actually forward-declare myPow()? Is a function prototype for it known at the time you use it in `testClass`?

Comment: I added the whole "working" code.

Comment: OK then, It's what chris said. Your `constexpr` function is not allowed to be more than a single `return` statement in C++11. The compiler error message already makes that apparent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11, a `constexpr` function can only contain a `return` statement (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for the full details), so your `myPow` function is not constexpr-compliant (because it contains a `for` loop).

You can use this metafunction to compute the integer power at compile-time:

```
template <int N, typename Type> 
constexpr Type pow(const Type& x) 
{
    return (N > 1) ? (x*pow<(N-1)*(N > 1)>(x)) 
                   : ((N < 0) ? (static_cast<Type>(1)/pow<(-N)*(N < 0)>(x)) 
                              : ((N == 1) ? (x) 
                                          : (static_cast<Type>(1))));
}
```

If you want to compute `2^N`, you can type:

```
pow<N>(2)
```

Note 1: this metafunction is very generic and also work for negative integers and floating-point types, so you can type : `pow<-3>(3.14)`

Note 2: the multiplication by `N>1` or `N<0` in the template are here to block infinite recursivity and force the template parameter to be equal to zero when the branch is not relevant. This could be done with template specialization, but the technique used here allow to write a single function.

Comment: Wow very nice! I was thinking about using metafunction but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Yes it is very generic and I really love it!!! Probably I'll give you some reward in 2 day if I don't forget about it ;)

Comment: But I would like to know why there is `(N>1)` and `(N<0)` in `pow<(N-1)*(N > 1)>` and `pow<(-N)*(N < 0)>(x)` ? It seams to me to be redundant.

Comment: Because when you write metafunctions, the compiler will try to instantiate all the branches even if they are not executed. So without this redudancy, the recursivity will not stop. So the `N>1`and `N<0` are here to force the template parameter to be equal to zero to avoid infinite recursivity. I will detail it in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11, `constexpr` functions are quite restricted, and your code doesn't comply with the restrictions (you can't declare variables, mutate local state, nor use most forms of statements -- including loops). However, C++1y removes most of the restrictions, and Clang 3.3 accepts your original code sample in its `-std=c++1y` mode.

If you need the code to work in C++11 mode, you can rewrite it to sidestep the `constexpr` restrictions:

```
constexpr int myPow(int a, int b) {
  return b ? a * myPow(a, b - 1) : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Goto Richard Smith's smarter answer.

It is not necessary to use a metafunction, as per your accepted answer,
to implement your `myPow` algorithm as a `constexpr`-qualified function.

You can just default the exponent argument = 0 and then:

```
constexpr int myPow(int a, int b = 0){
    return b == 0 ? 1 : myPow(a,b - 1) * a;
}
```

If you do not like defaulting that argument, then alternatively you can 
default that that argument in a `constexpr` auxiliary which `myPow` just 
invokes, e.g.

```
namespace impl {
    constexpr int myPow(int a, int b = 0){
        return b == 0 ? 1 : myPow(a,b - 1) * a;
    }
}
constexpr int myPow(int a, int b){
    return impl::myPow(a,b);
}
```

If and when you upgrade at least to gcc 4.7.2 you would be able with `-std=c++11`
even to hide that auxiliary within `myPow` itself, because you will be allowed
to define types within the body of a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr int myPow(int a, int b){
    struct _1 {
        static constexpr int _2(int a, int b = 0) {
            return b == 0 ? 1 : _2(a,b - 1) * a;
        }
    };
    return _1::_2(a,b);
}
```

(although I think strictly this latitude is a C++1y extension).

You might want to adapt Vincent's superior algorithm so that
it is no longer a metafunction in `N`, but is still generic at to
the arithmetic type.

Comment: The default argument is not necessary.

Comment: @RichardSmith Ha! How right you are! I will chop it accordingly.

Comment: @RichardSmith. ...no I won't chop it as I see that would now be copying your better answer.